# Why does my AWS Lambda stop before all my files have been downloaded when I used GetObjectCommand?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've programmed a Lambda function that is intended to retrieve a list of files from S3, create an archive with these files, and then download it back to S3. However, my Lambda stops executing before my promises, which fetch the list of files, are completed. Can you help me?

Here is my code :

```js
async function addFilesToArchive (files, archive) {
    try {
        addLog('addFilesToArchive - All Promise launched')
        await Promise.all(
            files.map((file) => uploadFileForArchivePromise(file, archive))
        )
        addLog('addFilesToArchive - All Promise Finished')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading files:', error)
        throw error
    }
}


function uploadFileForArchivePromise ({s3Path, pathInZip}, archive) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key:    s3Path
        })
        
        s3.send(getObjectCommand).then(({Body}) => {
            fileLaunchedCount++
            addLog('fileLaunchedCount = ' + fileLaunchedCount)
            addLog('file stream : ' + s3Path)

            Body.once('error', err => {
                addLog('addFilesToArchive - Body error:' + err)
                reject(err)
            })
            

            Body.once('end', () => {
                fileFinishedCount++
                addLog('fileFinishedCount = ' + fileFinishedCount)
                addLog('file stream : ' + s3Path)
            })
            
            archive.append(Body, {name: pathInZip})
            resolve()
        }).catch((error) => {
            addLog('addFilesToArchive - s3 send getObjectCommand error:' + error)
            reject(error)
        })

    })
}
```

In my logs, all the fileLaunchedCount was trigger but not all the fileFinishedCount.

This code works when given a small list of files (50 files), but starts to fail if the list is large and/or the files are large (100 files, > 300MB).

Thank you and have a great day.

Edit :
I forgot to mention: my timeout is set to 15 minutes (the maximum).

I don't have any errors caught.
And the lambda timeout wasn't trigger.

Lambda stops before everything is downloaded.
My logs are quite extensive, but I don't see anything after the 'await'.
For example, 'addFilesToArchive - All Promise Finished' is not logged.
Instead, I directly see:

````
2023-12-06T14:43:20.108+01:00 END RequestId: 2a907a0e-595d-4c4d-b5d8-b8350be776b0
2023-12-06T14:43:20.108+01:00 REPORT RequestId: 2a907a0e-595d-4c4d-b5d8-b8350be776b0 Duration: 735.65 ms```
````

Comment: What is the timeout of your lambda? and how much time does your lambda run for? max timeout is 15 min iirc.

Comment: When you say it "starts to fail" you need to be more specific. What does it do **exactly**? Is there an actual error message in the log? And if so, what is the actual error message? Or are some of the files simply not processed?

Comment: CloudWatch Logs will tell you if the Lambda function invocation timed out.

Answer (score 1):

This exact use case is documented in the AWS Example below.

This serverless app gets a list of images from an S3 bucket, places them into a ZIP file and places the ZIP into another bucket. The ZIP is then presigned and sent in a SNS email that contains the Presigned URL where the user can download the ZIP. All done via Lambda.

If you want to learn how to do this, i recommend going through the JavaScript Version and see it working in action. You issue could be timeout, wrong code, etc.

See

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_cross_PAM_section.html)

Comment: I don't know why, but it's work !
You saving my life :D thx !

Comment: This is why we develop these examples in the AWS Code lib. They are all tested, etc and work.

Comment: Probably still worth understanding why your code fails.